# PHP insert with array values,tablename

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, crud

I am struggling with a PHP insert statement. I want it to insert data into the database by using `array_keys($values)` and `array_values($values)`.

I have tried to work out how I can do this and so far I have this code in my insert and have also included my index page. I need to do it without changing the index page as it is a challenge I have to complete. I have analysed the index page and need to somehow make the function work with that to insert data into my database from the PHP insert command.

I also wonder if there's a way to wrap the PDO connection into one statement which I can use for this and other functions.

Insert Function

```
  <?php
function insert(array $values, $tablename)
{

    //cosntruct sql statment 


    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename $values";

    //pick apart vaules 


   //this line fetches the result set and fetch assoc to prevent multiple rows beign fetched 
    $ResultSet = dbconnect()->query($sql); 

   //returns the results 
   return $ResultSet;



    //array keys and array vaules


    //connection 



    // checks results 








} 

?>
```

Part of the Index page:

```
 if(isset($_POST['table']))
    {
        $tableName = $_POST['table'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['insert']))
    {
        $values = array();
        $tableName = $_POST['tablename'];

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
            if(!empty($value) && ($value != "Submit") && ($key != "insert") && ($key != "table") && ($key != "tablename"))
            {
                $values[$key] = $value;
            }
     } 
     $count = insert($values, $tableName);    
    }
```

Note that I am quite new at coding. Any suggestions?

Comment: Additionally that insert seems like invalid syntax and open to SQL injections. `insert into table (columns) values (ACTUAL values)`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks although currently no errors as i am struggle even to construct the statement, and is not a duplicate as i am not getting that error

Comment: You have a typo, should be `$values` in `$sql = "INSERT $vaules INTO $tablename";`

Comment: Please [check out the MYSQL Manual for the syntax for an INSERT statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) The manual should be your first port of call.

Comment: Thanks I have checked that but am very confused still, spent a few days on this one statement

Comment: Try looking at some tutorials [example](http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-pdo/)

Comment: Thanks I solved it with ('".implode("','",array_values($values))."')"; Although am unsure on what this does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it works fine for me. You just have to pass the name of the table and an associative array which has the name of the columns as keys.

```
public function insert($table, $data)
{

    $query='INSERT INTO '.$table.' (';
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $query .= $key.','; 
    }
    $query = substr($query, 0, -1);
    $query .= ') VALUES (';
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $query .= ':'.$key.',';
    }
    $query = substr($query, 0, -1);
    $query .= ');';

    $insert = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $insert->execute($data);

}
```

Comment: [This code is vulnerable to SQL injection](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/lame_update)