# How to store array values in a MySQL database

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I don't know how to store my array data in database, I only know fetching and displaying data. Any suggestion or discrimination is ok to me because i didn't get the logic and im a noob and newbie

```
    <?php
    $cart_statement = "SELECT * FROM user_cart WHERE email = '$email'";
    $cart_res = mysqli_query($con,$cart_statement);
    $storeArray = Array();
    $cart_num = mysqli_num_rows($cart_res);
    while ($cart_row = mysqli_fetch_array($cart_res)) {
        echo $storeArray[] =  $cart_row['product_name'].",";
    }
    ?>
```

mysql table user_cart

|- - - - - - |- - - - - - - - - - - -|
|  cart_id   | product_name  |
| - - - - - -|- - - - - - - - - - - -|
|- - -1 - - |- - -Laptop1 - - - |
|- - -2 - - |- - -Laptop2 - - - |
|- - - - - - |- - - - - - - - - - - -|

output i want is Laptop1,Laptop2

store in tbl_orders

|- - - - - - - |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - |
|  order_id   | - - - products - - - - -  |
| - - - - - - -|- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - |
|- - -1 - - - |- Laptop1, Laptop2  - |
|- - - - - -  - |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - |

sorry i dont know how to make tables here

Comment: for storing an array, you've to serialize it to save it in a single field or store the single values in different fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how to insert data from an array into multiple rows of your table? For that, you just need to create multiple `INSERT` queries, one for each array element, and execute them with the proper data bound to them. It's easiest to iterate through the array for this.

For example:

```
foreach ($cart_row as $value) {
    $stmt = "INSERT INTO user_cart(ProductName, Qty, Price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_prepare($con, $stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sii", $value["product_name"], $value["quantity"], $value["price"]);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Comment: insert it as one in my table data

Comment: Oh, so you want multiple values to be stored in a single field? There's no built-in way to do that, you'll have to decide on the format you want for yourself. You can use the implode() function to create a delimited list from your array and store that, or the serialize() function to automatically create a more robust, but less readable, string from it.

Comment: thats almost fixed my problem but i get Laptop1,Laptop2,Laptop1,Laptop2? i used implode();

Comment: oh sorry i just doubled the echo :) still your very helpful to me best answer big thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This function inserts multiple rows same question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36190690/6106973 .

You have to pass as the first parameter the name of the table and the second an associative array which has the name of the columns as keys like $data = ['column_name' => $value];

Here is the code, hope it helps

```
public function insert($table, $data)
{

    $query='INSERT INTO '.$table.' (';
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $query .= $key.','; 
    }
    $query = substr($query, 0, -1);
    $query .= ') VALUES (';
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $query .= ':'.$key.',';
    }
    $query = substr($query, 0, -1);
    $query .= ');';

    $insert = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $insert->execute($data);

}
```