# Inserting multipe rows to database but with different values in one query

Tags: php, mysql

i need help for my Cinema seat reservation...

I need some help for inserting multipe rows with different values to database using php.. because i need it to disabled checkbox when the values of checkbox are already exist on database..

here is my insert query :

```
    if ($bayargan > $totalbyr) {
        for($i = 1;$i <= $total; $i++){
        $transaksi = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_transaksi VALUES ('$idtrs','$idptg','$idflm','$idstd',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'$totalbyr','$kodekursi','$std')") or die(mysql_error());
        $idtrs++;
    }
```

Mmm... i mean like this..

There are seat selection[This is my seat reservation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiJ8H.png)

i choose 2 seats, F2 and F3, and then i submit it to insert it to Database
but, i want to make it into 2 rows with different seat values

So Thanks if you want to help me...
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Your code sample seems incomplete (opening braces do not match closing). And can you translate the variables for readability?

Lastly, please read the big warning on: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

You can provide multiple VALUES() in your INSERT statement.

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('value1', 'anothervalue1'), ('value2', 'anothervalue2')
```

I recommend adding the fields (and their order), so it'll look more like

```
INSERT INTO mytable (myfield, anotherfield) VALUES ('value1', 'anothervalue1'), ('value2', 'anothervalue2')
```

so that it'll be clear which fields you are setting and you don't have to look at the table definition to find out what's happening.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html for more about the INSERT syntax.

Answer (score -1):

This function might help you, it inserts multiple rows in the database by passing the name of the table and an associative array which has the name of the columns as keys :

```
public function insert($table, $data)
{

    $query='INSERT INTO '.$table.' (';
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $query .= $key.','; 
    }
    $query = substr($query, 0, -1);
    $query .= ') VALUES (';
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $query .= ':'.$key.',';
    }
    $query = substr($query, 0, -1);
    $query .= ');';

    $insert = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $insert->execute($data);
}
```

Similar question here : [PHP insert with array values,tablename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138058/php-insert-with-array-values-tablename/36190690#36190690)